# Adding a fragment,wrong 2nd argument

Tags: android

I created a fragment called "blankfragment" and when i try to add this fragment to my activity using fragmenttransaction it is showing an error saying "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.sainath.project.BlankFragment'(type of fragment I created with my package name), required: 'android.app.Fragment'".

```
 BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.relative,fragment,"blankfragment");
```

Comment: you are using app.support.v4.Fragment i guess, try replacing it with android.app.Fragment in BlankFragment

Comment: Got it...Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check what kind of Fragment you are extending (`Fragment` or `support.v4.app.Fragment`). If you are extending `support.v4.app.fragment` in your `BlankFragment` then you should call

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your BlankFragment is a app.support.v4.Fragment so you need to replace

```
getFragmentManager()
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```